Understanding Nethogs output
I am seeing two styles of Nethogs trace output.
First one looks like this:
Refreshing:
34.120.208.123:443-203.2.199.101:44816/0/0      0       0.101953
34.117.188.166:443-203.2.199.101:57670/0/0      0       0.101953
142.250.70.164:443-203.2.199.101:54780/0/0      0       0.101953
203.2.199.4:25-45.87.196.105:50855/0/0  0       0.0289063
sshd: scldad@pts/0/2538/1000    0.0355469       0.0128906
203.2.199.4:41683-83.222.191.74:52747/0/0       0.0105469       0.0117188
unknown TCP/0/0 0       0

and the second one looks like this:
Refreshing:
203.2.199.4:25-91.192.40.153:54680/0/0  0       0.0144531
203.2.199.4:14266-83.222.191.58:28114/0/0       0.0105469       0.0117188
194.180.49.198:46127-203.2.199.41:9471/0/0      0       0
203.2.199.4:35733-194.180.49.190:46227/0/0      0       0
203.2.199.4:9100-65.49.1.85:49493/0/0   0       0
203.2.199.4:1521-162.142.125.95:41425/0/0       0       0
203.2.199.4:1000-83.222.191.58:28114/0/0        0       0
203.2.199.4:23-1.34.212.100:16071/0/0   0       0
203.2.199.4:118-172.206.146.193:57185/0/0       0       0
184.105.247.223:55133-203.2.199.41:9200/0/0     0       0
203.2.199.4:17479-154.213.184.66:34431/0/0      0       0
203.2.199.4:40686-194.180.49.190:46227/0/0      0       0
83.222.191.74:52747-203.2.199.41:9544/0/0       0       0
203.2.199.4:5432-207.90.244.15:31667/0/0        0       0
203.2.199.4:10877-194.180.49.198:46127/0/0      0       0
unknown TCP/0/0 0       0

They are very similar but the second one has no mention of any process while the first one correctly mentions my SSH connection but nothing else. Nobody else was logged in.
How can I associate the other readings with the SSH session?
How come the second has no processes at all?
Where is the traffic coming from?
The second trace is from a period when nobody was logged into the server. How come HTTPS traffic is so prevalent?
(203.2.199.4 is my server and 203.2.199.101 is my workstation.)
